# About ECS not scaling out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Deployment rarely fails when deploying with ECS.
The reason is that there is not enough instance capacity and deploying is not possible.
Therefore, I decided to set up scale-out and scale out when I run out of capacity when deploying.
However, I configured scale-out settings in the ECS service.
As for the contents, I set the minimum number of tasks to 2 and the maximum number of tasks to 4.
However, the scale-out is not executed when the capacity of the instance is about to be exceeded during deployment.
What is the cause?

We are using ECSonEC2. Is there any reason why scale-out is not performed because we are using EC2?

Comment: Min/Max tasks will not affect the number of the underlying instances - you will need to configure out EC2 autoscaling group for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the number of EC2 instances available in your cluster. You have configured the scale-out settings for the ECS tasks. This is totally unrelated to the number of EC2 instances in the cluster.

You need to configure a cluster [capacity provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html) with an EC2 auto-scaling group in order for ECS to automatically add EC2 instances to the cluster when they are needed.